# How to resize window to content of WPF page by code and then lock window resizing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a TicTacToe game in WPF for a school project. The idea is that in first page, the player selects the grid size and then in another, the code creates appropriate number of buttons with 100x100 px size, each of which is has 20px of space between them, where they also have initial space of 10 pixels at the start and the end of page.

The entire thing is handled on only two pages, so I have to resize the window dynamically between them, similarly to Minesweeper app on old Windows systems, then lock its ability to be resized. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Consider to improve the question by adding screenshots, your current xaml, what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work. I have difficulty to imagine *"similarly to Minesweeper app on old Windows systems"* - how does that looks like?

Answer (score 0):

To disallow the user to resize the `Window` set the `Window.ResizeMode` property to `ResizeMode.NoResize`:

```
<Window ResizeMode="NoResize">
</Window>
```